# Remove stopwords from Grafana user searches panel (elastic)

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have the following user searches panel in Grafana, and I want to remove stopwords like "and". While I've been able to do it using a Ruby filter in Logstash, I think I'd prefer to store the stopwords in Elastic for completeness and have Grafana remove them. However I don't know how to tell it "count search_terms.keyword when search_terms.keyword is not in ['and', 'or', ...]".

[image: Grafana user searches panel]

Note: Each time a user searches for something on our web site, a document like the following is eventually created (through Logstash/gelf) in elastic (in this example, the user searched for "hello world and planet"):

```
{
    "_index" : "user_searches-2022.05.05",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "PyBPk4ABFBQAcon8zqyD",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "message" : """172.18.0.21 - - [05/May/2022:08:22:02 +0000] "GET /index.php?search=hello+world+and+planet&title=%CE%95%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%3A%CE%91%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B6%CE%AE%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns102=1&ns108=1 HTTP/1.0" 200 10965 "http://mitos.test/index.php?search=%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1+%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%B5+%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9+%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1+%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%82&title=%CE%95%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%3A%CE%91%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B6%CE%AE%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns102=1&ns108=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"""",
      "search_terms" : [
        "hello",
        "world",
        "and",
        "planet"
      ],
      "@timestamp" : "2022-05-05T08:22:02.388Z"
}
```

Comment: If I understand it, you want to store the stopwords in Elasticsearch index but remove it when querying ? I m not aware of grafana but can tell you how to do it at Elasticsearch level if you wanrt

Comment: @Amit Thanks! Yes, that's what I want. I'm not certain it will be easy to do it in Grafana once I understand how to do it in Elastic, but solving part of the problem would definitely help. Grafana has a field for specifying a "Lucene" query. If it's not done with a "Lucene" query but with some other kind of query then maybe it will be more difficult. (I'm not sure I'm making much sense, I'm still a beginner with Elastic.)